# WPF OpenFileDialog with Win32 parent window; window is not regaining focus when closed

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, c++-cli, openfiledialog

I have a c++ windows app calling into a c++/cli library, which is calling into a managed library.  The managed library is calling OpenFileDialog.Show with a WPF window parent which is owned by the Win32 window.  I haven't found a better way to do this, and all the resources I've read here and searching google and social.msdn recommend doing what I'm doing.

The dialog opens just fine, but when I hit the cancel button, for instance, the app loses focus completely.  I'm not sure why it's happening, but I can't seem to make it stop.  I've tried a number of different things to no avail.

If I just launch the OpenFileDialog without creating a WPF Window, I don't see the problem.
If I don't set the owner of the WPF Window, I don't see the problem.  If I call OpenFileDialog.Show and don't pass the parent, but still create the WPF Window and set its owner, I still see the problem.

I am able to hack it to set the parent app window to foreground after it loses focus, but I would like to not have to.

I have uploaded a small example solution for my scenario that illustrates the problem:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26054523/MixedExample.zip

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running the dialog on a same thread? Both WinForms and Win32 are single-threaded. It probably doesn't like you opening the dialog from another thread.

Comment: Yes, I have, it won't allow it.  The reason for opening in another thread is because WPF seems to want to run in an STA thread.

Comment: I have a similar problem with C#. For some reason, once the OpenFileDialog is dismissed (Through OK or cancel) the program loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried inverting the hosting scenario? Right now it sounds like you're going unmanaged->bridge->managed->WPF->Winforms. Maybe you could go ...managed->WinForms->WPF using ElementHost http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx

In that way, the WPF window would just be a child control of the WinForms app and that might work out better for focus switches. WinForms controls are not really meant to work directly with WPF apps so well, two different UI threading setups are being used as you've noted.

Comment: That is a significant change given the size and complexity of the unmanaged codebase.  Also, there's not really any WinForms.  The goal was unmanaged windows calling into managed WPF only.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. At work, we have more or less recoded the open file dialog directly in WPF to work with our windowing system. It's kind of a pain that there's not better stock options for that, and I see it as one of the general problems of WPF: stock dialog boxes can be tricky unless you code your own and then they're a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post but I think that this is a common problem and I have a good answer. If you have a Win32 window parent window called ParentWindow and a WPF child window called WPFChild you can do this:

```
using System.Windows.Interop;

void OpenWindow()
{
    WPFChildWindow WPFChild = new WPFChildWindow();
    WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(WPFChild)
    {
        Owner = new NativeWindowWrapper(ParentWindow.Hwnd).Handle
    };
    bool? ret = _stepsForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

This will cause the child window to remain on top of the parent and function as a dialog. Keep in mind that the WPF window does not return a DialogResult but rather a nullable bool.

NativeWindow wrapper is a simple class that takes casts an int as an IntPtr. It's actually from a .net Excel ref edit project located here: [How to code a .NET RefEdit ControlT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gabhan_berry/archive/2008/06/12/net-refedit-control.aspx)